# how to disable red pop up in home screen iphone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, popup, homescreen

when i am start video calling and press home button in red pop up is display on home screen.how to hide this red pop up in home screen.I have search but not getting and solution.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

iOS turns the bar red as a service to your end-users, reminding them that that their audio or video is currently on. This serves as an alert of potentially being recorded by the app running in the background. This reminder makes it harder for them to start and forget a running app, potentially letting others to "spy" on them.

The only way to not have that bar when the user switches to home screen is to not run your app in the background with the microphone turned on.

Comment: Please provide any sample link or demo code.

Comment: Even if you make your app not record in the background it will still be presenten when your users exit your app, but only for few seconds. There is not way to sepres it.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is controlled by iOS platform on its own. Background modes which are using critical system resources (Microphone, locations) shows a "Bar" (red/blue) when the app is running and still using the resources. You can't hide this bar from your app code.